# How to fix : "list index out of range ..." in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

I tried to make a Conway's Game of Life in Python. I want to test if the box isn't a border box, check the boxes that are all around, etc.

I've already tried to put this tests in comments and randomize the number of neighbors cells alive. The error disappears but another problem came
and this is not the subject of this question.

```py
newArr = arr
    rows = 0
    while rows < maxRows :
        cols = 0
        while cols < maxCols :
            if cols != 0 and cols != maxCols and rows != 0 and rows != maxRows :
                checks = 0
                if arr[cols-1][rows-1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols][rows-1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols+1][rows-1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols+1][rows] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols+1][rows+1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols][rows+1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols-1][rows+1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols-1][rows] == '██':
                    checks += 1

                if arr[rows][cols] == '  ' and checks == 3 :
                    newArr[rows][cols] == '██'
                if arr[rows][cols] == '██' and checks > 2 and checks < 3 :
                    newArr[rows][cols] == '██'
                else :
                    newArr[rows][cols] == '  '
            cols += 1
        rows += 1
    arr = newArr
```

Here is the error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/acer/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Test.py", line 55, in <module>
    if arr[cols+1][rows-1] == '██' :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: If e.g. `cols = maxCols - 1`, `cols + 1` will be beyond the end of the list (assuming `maxCols = len(cols)`). Note that the check `cols != maxCols` is redundant because that block only runs `while cols < maxCols:`.

Comment: Here it is glhr, sorry if I'm late.

Comment: Okay thank you a lot jonshrape
Here is the code now ( a partial )
```python
while rows < maxRows :
        cols = 0
        while cols < maxCols :
            if cols != 0 and cols != maxCols - 1 and rows != 0 and rows != maxRows - 1 :
                checks = 0
                if arr[cols-1][rows-1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
                if arr[cols][rows-1] == '██' :
                    checks += 1
```
...

Comment: Try to print `cols` and `rows` before all the `if` (line 7 I guess) and you will see when it exceeds `arr` size.

Comment: Instead of `rows = 0; while rows < maxRows: ... rows += 1` just do `for rows in range(maxRows):` already, it also fixed the off-by-one error since it only goes up to `maxRows-1`. Ditto do `for cols in range(maxCols):`

Comment: The condition `if cols != 0 and cols != maxCols and rows != 0 and rows != maxRows :` is unwieldy; `cols` can only ever have (at most) one of those two extreme values, ditto `rows`. Use bracketing or `or` statements. Or else if you're sure you can skip the edge rows/cols entirely, you could simply run your loops: `for rows in range(1, maxRows-1): ... for cols in range(1, maxCols-1): `

Comment: And if `arr` simply represented cells as integer zeros or ones (the natural choice) or True/False instead of character values, you could write your `checks` code as simply a direct summation over that subrange of values. (The only time you really need `arr` to be character values is when you're displaying it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row in range(1, maxRows - 1):
    for col in range(1, maxCols - 1):
        aliveNeighbours = 0
        for i in range(-1, 2):
            for j in range(-1, 2):
                if arr[i + row][j + cols] = 'Your symbol' and (i != 0 or j != 0):
                    aliveNeighbours += 1
    #Then check for various conditions for conways' game of life
```

This checks for alive neighbours around a cell.
We don't need the rows and columns at the edges.

```
>>> for i in range(-1, 2):
...     for j in range(-1, 2):
...             if i != 0 or j != 0:
...                     print(i, j)
... 
-1 -1
-1 0
-1 1
0 -1
0 1
1 -1
1 0
1 1
>>>
```

This checks for every cell except it's own which is 0, 0.
Comment if anything can be improved.

Comment: Nice. I would just call the `i, j` variables `deltaX, deltaY` or `deltaR, deltaC` since they are deltas to the `(row,col)` coordinates.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to get fancier, you could have the 8 legal `i,j` values generated as tuples by a generator `neighbors_of(row,col)`. Then the `alive` computation becomes a one-liner summing integer values of `arr`, and you avoid the explicit `... and (i != 0 or j != 0)` check.